# SQL High Sharable Memory

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a problem in my Oracle BBDD. A query consumes a lot of SGA, until the BBDD start to give the error ORA-04031 and I have to reset it.

In the AWR i can see the Query, in the "SQL ordered by Sharable Memory". The query appears a lot of times in this section, one by each distinct "or's", example:

Query 1:

```
...My Query... WHERE ( inc.ID =:"SYS_B_131"
  OR inc.ID                  =:"SYS_B_132"
  OR inc.ID                  =:"SYS_B_133"
  OR inc.ID                  =:"SYS_B_134" )
```

Query 2:

```
...My Query... WHERE ( inc.ID =:"SYS_B_131"
  OR inc.ID                  =:"SYS_B_132"
  OR inc.ID                  =:"SYS_B_133"
  OR inc.ID                  =:"SYS_B_134"
  OR inc.ID                  =:"SYS_B_135"
  OR inc.ID                  =:"SYS_B_136"
  OR inc.ID                  =:"SYS_B_137"
  OR inc.ID                  =:"SYS_B_138" )
```

Etc, etc.

My question is, the Query with 4 "or" items have a memory consumption of 3MB, the query with 500 "or" items have of memory consumption of 1GB , ¿Is this normal?

Comment: Are you using cursor_sharing set to similar or force? The best solution would be to force the application to use bind variables.

Comment: Yes, cursor Sharing is set to "FORCE".

Comment: Do Not Use CURSOR_SHARING = FORCE as a Permanent Fix. Default is CURSOR_SHARING=EXACT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have find the problem. Is a Oracle Bug. In my version of Oracle BBDD, if the  Query has a lot of bind variables, the query execution plan consumes a lot of SGA (Until 1.2Gb for only a Query).

I have rewrite the Query for replace a "IN" list of values by a SubQuery, and the problem solves.

Answer (score 0):

I would not call it a bug. It’s a rather a sensible limitation set by Oracle with good intentions to prevent a single query chocking most of precious SGA memory. 
Applying 500 "IN" list predicates is simply not suggested practice (with or without binds). Moreover, just pushing 500 "IN" list predicates  in Subquery alone will not help here.
We should store all these 500 odd IDs in a small table and indexed FK and apply EXISTS subquery like -

```
SELECT <col list> FROM MainTable inc
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM 500_IDTable inc2 inc.ID = inc2.ID);
```

Though you NOT have shared the modified Query/SubQuery, That’s what you must have done, I guess.

@ibre5041 – Query posted above already using bind var. In fact, too many bind variables.

Ildelian – We should NEVER use CURSOR_SHARING = FORCE as a Permanent Fix. Should use ‘EXACT’ instead. Default is CURSOR_SHARING=EXACT.

See why https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4608916500346512056

The use of cursor_sharing=force has shown benefits for database plagued with literals (i.e. non-reentrant SQL) in their library cache.

In your case, CURSOR_SHARING = FORCE not making any sense at all because you seem to be using bind variable already.

Please consider changing CURSOR_SHARING =EXACT as well.